# Appium & Python: How to move to another app?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, appium

I am making a testing bot with Python and Appium.

I need to extract the email of a button. I tired to extract href, but button are obviously something else than  in smartphone applications.

So I click on this button which open my gmail with the New message window and the email in the "To" field.

SO I investigate and I could find only 1 tutoriel in Java :-(.

I found something else. SOmeone propose to instantiate new driver:

```
driver2 = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps2)
print("we setup driver2")
email = driver2.find_element_by_id("com.google.android.gm:id/to").text
```

But it stop immediately the browser. ANd Pycharm displayed this error:

> Error Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py",
>   line 59, in testPartExecutor
>       yield   File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py",
>   line 628, in run
>       testMethod()   File "C:\Users\Nino\PycharmProjects\mybot\mybot_mybot.py", line 92, in
>   test_scrap_email
>       email = driver2.find_element_by_id("com.google.android.gm:id/to").text   File
>   "C:\Users\Nino\PycharmProjects\mybot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 360, in find_element_by_id
>       return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)   File "C:\Users\Nino\PycharmProjects\mybot\venv\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py",
>   line 276, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "C:\Users\Nino\PycharmProjects\mybot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Nino\PycharmProjects\mybot\venv\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py",
>   line 29, in check_response
>       raise wde   File "C:\Users\Nino\PycharmProjects\mybot\venv\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py",
>   line 24, in check_response
>       super(MobileErrorHandler, self).check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Nino\PycharmProjects\mybot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element
>   could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

I am using unittest which instantiate one driver going to 1 app (where there si the email button), then I instantiate in the middle of the code a new driver.
But it bugs. And Icannot find anywhere an article or forum question about switching from 1 app to other app.

I prefer to let you te code of my bot:

```
from datetime import time
from time import sleep

from appium import webdriver
import unittest

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class apptotest1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps['platformName']='Android'
        desired_caps['platformVersion']='6.0'
        desired_caps['deviceName']='S6S5IN3G'
        desired_caps['noReset']='true'
        desired_caps['appPackage']='com.apptotest1'
        desired_caps['appActivity']=' com.apptotest1.android/com.apptotest1.android.activity.MainTabActivity'

        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',desired_caps)
        #self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub',desired_caps)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_scrap_email(self):
        search_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//android.widget.ImageView[@bounds='[126,800][162,836]']")
        #search_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH ("//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc='Rechercher et explorer']"))
        if search_button:
            print("search_button was found!")
            search_button.click()

        else:
            print("search_button was not found :-(")

        search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.apptotest1.android:id/action_bar_search_edit_text')
        search_field.send_keys('marketing')
        users_button = self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.apptotest1.android:id/tab_button_fallback_icon')
        if users_button:
            print("users_button was found!")
            users_button.click()


        else:
            print("users_button was not found :-(")


        users_button2 = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//android.widget.ImageView[@bounds='[162,123][198,159]']")

        if users_button2:
            print("users_button2 was found!")
            users_button2.click()

        else:
            print("users_button2 was not found :-(")

        sleep(5)
        profile_test = self.driver.find_elements_by_id("com.apptotest1.android:id/row_search_user_username")[1]
        if profile_test:
            print("profile_test was found!")
            profile_test.click()


        else:
            print("profile_test was not found :-(")

        sleep(5)

        button_email = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//android.widget.TextView[@text='Adresse e-mail']")
        if button_email:
            print("button_email was found!")

            button_text = button_email.text
            print("button_text is :" + str(button_text))
            button_email.click()

        else:
            print("button_email was not found :-(")



        desired_caps2 = {}
        desired_caps2['platformName'] = 'Android'
        desired_caps2['platformVersion'] = '6.0'
        desired_caps2['deviceName'] = 'S6S5IN3G'
        desired_caps2['noReset'] = 'true'
        desired_caps2['appPackage'] = 'com.google.android.gm'
        desired_caps2['appActivity'] = ' com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmailExternal'

        driver2 = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps2)
        print("we setup driver2")
        email = driver2.find_element_by_id("com.google.android.gm:id/to").text
        sleep(10)
        if email:
            print("email was found!")
            print("Es eso que querias :-) =>" + str(email))



        else:
            print("Email was not found :-(")


        sleep(5)





if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.Testloader().loadTestsFromTestCase(apptotest1)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(suite)
```

Does anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for [`start_activity` function](https://github.com/appium/python-client#start-an-arbitrary-activity)

> The driver.start_activity method opens arbitrary activities on a device. **If the activity is not part of the application under test, it will also launch the activity's application**.
>
> ```
> driver.start_activity('com.foo.app', '.MyActivity')
> ```

This way you should be able to switch between applications within the bounds of the same [`webdriver` instance](https://github.com/appium/python-client#usage)

You might also find [`Launch` command](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Launch) useful as it is cross-platform approach allowing kicking off any installed application. The command is available via [SeeTest Appium Extension](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SeeTest+-+Appium+Extension).

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T. It didn't show me error message and it start the gmail app. The problem is the email disapeared as it is some kind of new sessio. When my bot is in my first app, it click on button where there is email. an it open the gmail app with the message and email ready to send. I didn't succeed to scrap it. from first app. So my idea was to make move the bot to this new window gmail app and scrap the email. With start_activity, it open completly new message frame without the email. I checked the doc and I couldn't find any other parameters. Do you have any other isuggestion?

Comment: Instead of using UI to read the email you could do the same by means of Python: https://medium.com/@sdoshi579/to-read-emails-and-download-attachments-in-python-6d7d6b60269

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T. I read the tutorial. It ias about reading mails from a mailbox. My case is about scraping an email from a smartphone. As I am not able to extract email from button, I need to click on button which open email client (in my case: gmail), and then focus on this new frame to extract email from gmailapp actual frame where email is in field "To:". I didn't see the idea you suggested with this python tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just need `switch context`, you facing web in `gmail`, try :

```
driver2 = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps2)
print("we setup driver2")
driver2.switch_to.context('WEBVIEW_1')
email = driver2.find_element_by_id("com.google.android.gm:id/to").text
```

Or

```
# switch to webview
webview = driver.contexts.last
driver.switch_to.context(webview)
```

And please try without new initilize `driver2`

Please read [this](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/) reference and [this](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/context/set-context/).

Comment: Thanks @frianH. I tested both. The 1rst one "WEBVIEW_1" give me this error "appium.common.exceptions.NoSuchContextException: Message: No such context found."............ . And the second one tell me ".last" doesn't exist